# Print Inbound and outbound Payload logs jersey REST API And Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey

I am using Spring with Jersey REST API for REST webservices.
I want print the inbound and outbound Payloads (XML Requests Data) to log file/console.

Is there any way todo this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LoggingFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/filter/LoggingFilter.html) can help you with that. You need to provide an instance of this filter to JAX-RS runtime - by default the entity is not printed. See code samples is [Registering Resources and Providers in Jersey 2](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/) to see how to register your logger (I am using `LoggingFilter` in these samples).